# VS 2010 ClickOnce - Specify URL for Offline Installation?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I'm using Visual Basic 2010 Express Edition on a Win7 machine.  I want to install a program using ClickOnce so that it will be available offline (available in my Start Menu).  I have set the Publishing Folder to a location on my hard drive.  I set the install mode to "Application is available offline as well (launchable from Start Menu).  When I select Publish Now, I get the message "Please specify and install URL."

Why will it not install to the Publishing Folder?  How do I correct this?

[image: InstallURLMessage]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The publishing file location is where you want to publish the application to.

The installation URL is where you want to install it from.

You might publish it to a folder on your C drive, then put it on a webserver. That's why those two are different.

Answer (score 3):

VS 2019:

Click "Updates" and uncheck "The application should check for updates"
Since is an offline installation, it should not check for updates

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the publish path must be a network path or a web URL and cannot be in the form I show above.  I was able to deploy and make the application available offline by using the home network path to the installation folder of my laptop:  \\Users\Tim\Documents\Temp\Installations\OCRLibrary\

Comment: You can point to your local drive, but you must disable the updates first